# PHP : SQL STATE 22007 when inserting date or datetime

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, pdo

My problem is:
I have a database, i'm trying to insert a simple date of creation in my table.
I set the field type to "date", and when i'm inserting the values via PDO in my php code, it's not working.

Well actually, the database is taking the data and inserting properly, but I still get the following error from php for some reason :

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '1' for column 'creation' at row 1

This is when I try to insert the following values :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions VALUES (NULL,'"
       .$values['type_question']
       ."','"
       .$values['question']
       ."', NULL , NOW() )"
;
```

I'm confused because when I open phpMyAdmin or the mysql console and paste the code (I do a var_dump of my SQL), it works without any problem.

I tried the following combinations:
Field type : Date, Datetime
Value : NOW(), CURRENT_DATE(), date('Y-m-d H:i:s') from PHP
None of it is working.

I get either the error above, either the same error code but with a different message saying something like:

> Incorrect value for field 'creation' at row 1

I really don't understand where it's coming from ...
Could it be a bug from PHP7 PDO? Do i do something bad?

Edit : 
PHP 7.0.0
Mysql 5.7.9

Solved by modifying the my.ini file, thanks.

Comment: Without DDL it is impossible for us to see which data you are putting in which column. Add the DDL of the table or use explicit column names in your `INSERT` query.

Answer (score 1):

Check your my.ini file, remove STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from sql-mode if it's there.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/authpuppy/+bug/907203)

Answer (score 0):

I have this line in my my.ini file :
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"

So, should I remove the "STRICT_ALL_TABLES" , and leave the rest be ?

I just tried it, it seems to solve the problem (I have now other errors with the request, but not linked to date / datetime), i'll keep updating to be sure it has nothing to do with it.

NB : The new error is a SQL STATE 23000 Integrity constraint violation. But the insert goes correctly and the inserted value is also correct, Again the error is coming from PHP rather than MYSQL ... -_-
The field is set with a default value, and can be NULL, i have an error if I put NULL, '', or a correct FK value in my request.

Edit : Solved. Wrong table name, nothing to do with the date/datetime as i thought, just me and my brain.